# How do I bind a textarea value to a model in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a textarea in a template:

```
{{textarea id="notes" name="notes" value=App.notes.body}}
```

In the route's activate method it does this:

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function () {
        App.note = store.find('note', {user_id: App.user.id});
    }
});
```

Note is a model defined as follows:

```
App.Note = DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    user_id: DS.attr('number')
});
```

This is clearly incorrect, because although I am getting JSON back from the server, nothing is displayed in the textarea.

What is the correct way to create a two way binding between the App.notes model and the textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `store.find`, a promise like object is returned instead of the model, and `App.note = ...` doesn't notify the observes, and to your textarea update you need to trigger that observes. To do this is needed to use the `set(propertyName, value)`. Your updated sample is the following:

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function () {
        this.store.find('note', {user_id: App.user.id}).then(function(note) {
            App.set('note', note);
        })
    }
});
```

But we can improve that sample using the model method, and set the note in the afterModel:

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('note', {user_id: App.user.id});
    },
    afterModel: function(note) {
        App.set('note', note);
    }
});
```

So you can take advantage of [ember loading and errors substates](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) to show loading messages, error messages etc

Also there is a typo in your template you need to update to `App.note.body`:

```
{{textarea id="notes" name="notes" value=App.note.body}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's almost working; it's just that the model doesn't appear to be ready in the afterModel function. I can change the model method to use createRecord to test it and it works (attributes are present), but from the store.find, nothing. I suspect the problem may be the format of the API response for a singular model. That may warrant another question!

Comment: You are welcome! It's possible because store.find touch the server, createRecord just create a instance, with the passed arguments.

Comment: It turned out that I needed to pluralise the API's output in terms of the array key and the results - i.e. wrapping the single returned json inside an array.